# Linq not returning List returning 1 row

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Well I have around 1000 records and it just returning 1 row.
I have more then 200 records which have `report_id = 2` and it has `client_id` in both table but it is returning only one the first one

```
var td = (from r in _entities.client3
          join s in _entities.report  on r.client_id equals s.client_id
          where s.report_id == 2
          select new
          {
              s.date,
              r.first_name,
              r.last_name,
              r.dob,
              r.gender,
              r.zip_code,
              r.hiv_date,
              s.is_state,
          }).ToList();
```

Comment: Check the generated query directly in the database and see what you get. I think your data is not what you are expecting

Comment: But how many of those 200 reports with a report id of 2 have a match in the client table?

Comment: Have you tried using 'foreach' to loop through the result?

Comment: @GiladGreen i run that same query on Sql it is showing me 100 records

Comment: @juharr 100 records

Comment: @AlfMoh i was thinking about foreach loop

Comment: Your structure would imply that there would be only one report record with report_id = 2 (I'm assuming that is the primary key of the report table otherwise your naming is off) so the query should return only one row, with the report record and it's corresponding client. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Agha The same query? Can you add the query to your post?

Comment: By bad the fields names are so improper  i was searching in s.report_id and there is another field with the name of reports_id :(

Comment: Query is working fine :) just change the name

Answer (score 1):

The `Join` is the most likely culprit which is the failure point. Research why the join on operation is failing and that will result in more data. Also one can run the query in *LinqPad* and switch it to a SQL view which you can run against the database. That might help you determine why it is failing.